# unique id in java thread

Tags: java, multithreading, unique, synchronized, identifier

My application uses a logging component which needs to keep track of a unique identifier for each call.

My starting point is an MDB which obviously initiates a series of methodcalls to several classes.
Each class creates a new logger-object, similar to log4j, and uses this to log events to the database. And for each logger-object that gets created, a unique identifier is assigned to it. This identifier should follow the thread until the subsequent calls all return and the onMessage-method in my MDB terminates.

The problem is that during the processing of one JmsMessage,  another message is received by the MDB and my IDs get mixed up.

I have been banging my head against the desk for some time now and I guess the answer is right in front of me, but have you got any ideas? How can I make sure that one "process" can log using its own ID even if another is started before the first one finishes?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you can't use [`Message.getJMSMessageID()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Message.html#getJMSMessageID%28%29) ?

If there is, [`AtomicLong.incrementAndGet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html#incrementAndGet%28%29) should be all it takes. Keep one static instance, and in the MDB's `onMessage()` method get an ID and keep it around while the message is processed (perhaps in a `ThreadLocal`).

Comment: The problem isn´t really obtaining an ID, I get an ID when I create the logger-object. The problem is keeping the ID consistent for each thread. 

Perhaps if I give you som pseudo-code:
`onMessage(){
log = LogFactory.getLogger();
messageHandler.processMessage();
}

processMessage(){
log = LogFactory.getLogger();
...processing message
...
}`

So by the time messageA is processed another messageB has been received and a different ID has been generated. The thread which processes MessageA should still use the first ID, while the second thread should use the second ID.

Comment: Do be aware that use of something like AtomicLong doesn't provide uniqueness across processes, nor does it survive a process restart without being primed to some value.  If you cannot use the message ID, you may want to instead create a unique thread identifier (say something like IP address + random UUID) and use that in conjunction with the AtomicLong.

Comment: @user1157155: yes, the problem very much *is* obtaining an ID when it's generated implicitly and you have no control over it. It looks like you need to change your LogFactory, perhaps have it take the ID as parameter to getLogger()

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: No, I get my ID from the database when I ask for a logger-object, so that I have control over, by calling my  'LogFactory.getSessionId()'  What I couldn´t control was which thread was logging against which ID, but it seems ThreadLocal solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you want to use the "friendly" name

```
String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
```

However, this might no be unique or meaningful in which case you can use a unique id.

```
int id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
```

Comment: I don't think that's going to work - most Java EE servers use thread pools to process requests, so the thread ID will not be unique per message.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey  When I use `Thread.currentThread().getName()` I get `Thread name: [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'>` as output, which is not very helpful. `Thread.currentThread().getId()` only gives me a two-digit int, which is a little less than I am looking for.

Comment: You should be free to give the thread a more meaningful name.  If you won't do it for you automatically, you will have to come up with a name which is meaningful to you.